# How to return the last id in JSON using JSON Extractor in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter, extract

Here is my response code I want to retrieve the last id always using JSON extractor and further how can I pass this **id** to another HTTP Request in POST parameter

```
        {
            "response": [
                {
                    "dm": "CL 6",
                    "id": 3,
                    "yN": "t1-cl -6"
                },
                {
                    "dm": "CL 2",
                    "id": 4,
                    "yN": "t1- cl -2"
                }
            ],
            "timestamp": "2020-04-02T22:40:42.416",
            "status": "OK"
        }
```

What I have tried in JSON extractor

[image]

but it does not return anything. I even tried  `$..id[-1]`

further, I need to pass this **id** to another HTTP Request in POST parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as JSON Path Expressions: `$.response[-1:].id`

This will return the last `id` from the `response` array objects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration should generate the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

```
extract_id_1=3
extract_id_2=4
extract_id_matchNr=2
```

[image]

So the "last" ID can be obtained using [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) as follows:

```
${__V(extract_id_${extract_id_matchNr})}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/)